# J2me List with filter

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I am working on j2me project and i want to implement the list with search option same like contacts like when we press p then it filters all the contacts start with p. I want to implement same thing on list please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: Please rephrase your question by adding relevant code sample, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Otherwise, it's quite difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that some people devoted my question, but its okay and i have found the answer of my question that is:

in j2me Polish we have Filtered list by that we can add the functionality of searching as

```
import de.enough.polish.ui.FilteredList;
FilteredList record = null;
this.record = new FilteredList("Records", List.IMPLICIT);


and this list can not implement action listener directly like,
```

//  addCommandListener(record); // error 
    but you can implement command listener as

```
 record.setCommandListener(this);
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use lwuit to develop such task , its already implemented and easy to use for multiple purposes .

please check this [example](http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2008/06/lightweight-text-input-in-lwuit.html) (LWUIT)